# Chrome: Youtube will play videos but no functionality on any interactions on page

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I'm having a really weird problem with Chrome.

Google Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m

When I go to YouTube I can watch videos, but on the video page, clicking on any interactions such as the Share tab, Add to, Show more, or any comments there is no response. My page also doesn't display correctly, my Guide on the left hand side is completely gone, and all of the video thumbnails are gone. I've Googled this issue and the fixes I found said to disable the Flash plugin, and then re-enable it. This corrected the issue the first time I tried, after that it failed to work. I also tried deleting all of my cache for YouTube with no luck. I am getting an error in the Console: `(3) Blocked a frame with origin 'https://www.youtube.com' from accessing a frame with origin 'https://apis.google.com'. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

I'm assuming this must be part of the issue, my first instinct was to disable my Disconnect and ADB extensions, but this didn't seem to fix the issue.

Here is a screenshot of what my YouTube page looks like:

[image: YouTube not working, also GWAR]

From the screenshot you can see that the guide isn't loading, and how the video thumbnails are also not loading to the right.

Comment: I thought it was just me. Been doing it for about 6 months. Haven't commented on any videos since then. Probably a good thing (I'm a closet troll).